# Is there a way to specify the order of sections in a sunburst chart with plotly?

Tags: r, plotly, sunburst-diagram

I know the order by default is by the width of the section but can I override this and specify the order of the sections somehow using plotly in R?

```
library(plotly)

clin2 <- data.frame(
stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
ids = c("MGH","CU","MGH - WT",
      "CU - WT","MGH - KDM","CU - KDM","MGH - G2032R",
      "MGH - S1986F","MGH - D2033N","CU - L1951R/L2026M"),
labels = c("Gainor<br>et al. 2017",
         "McCoach<br>et al. 2018","ROS1<br>Extrinsic",


"ROS1<br>Extrinsic","ROS1<br>Intrinsic","ROS<br>Intrinsic","G2032R",
         "S1986F","D2033N","L1951R/<br>L2026M"),
  parents = c(NA,NA,"MGH","CU","MGH",
          "CU","MGH - KDM","MGH - KDM","MGH - KDM","CU - KDM"),
  values = c(17L, 12L, 8L, 11L, 9L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
  colors = c("#111111", "#e6550d", "#9ecae1", "#fdae6b", "#9ecae1",
         "#fdae6b", "#deebf7", "#deebf7", "#deebf7", "#fee6ce")
)

clin2_plot <- plot_ly(clin2, ids = ~ids, labels = ~labels, parents = 
~parents, 
                  values = ~values, type = 'sunburst', branchvalues 
= 'total'
) %>% layout(sunburstcolorway = ~colors)

clin2_plot
```

[i.e. change level 2 to be intrinsic-extrinsic-intrinsic-extrinsic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fySOO.png)

Comment: Hey Clare, 
First think I would try is to change the grouping variable into an ordered factor. Would you be able to provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Edited to add an example of code and plot

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing that. It may be an issue with the version of R/Plotly. Can you try adding:
 `ids = ordered(c("MGH","CU","MGH - WT",
      "CU - WT","MGH - KDM","CU - KDM","MGH - G2032R",
      "MGH - S1986F","MGH - D2033N","CU - L1951R/L2026M"), 
c("MGH","CU","MGH - WT",
      "CU - WT","MGH - KDM","CU - KDM","MGH - G2032R",
      "MGH - S1986F","MGH - D2033N","CU - L1951R/L2026M")` to make them ordered?

Comment: Still in the same order, but doesn't break anything